# Schtasks backup - can't get the formatting right

Tags: cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a task on a Windows 2008 server but can't get the formatting right.

Here's what I have:

```
schtasks /create /sc hourly /tn "Backup QB every hour" /tr wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:R:\QBBackups\ -include:D:\Quickbooks Data Files
```

Something tells me that the spaces in "Quickbooks Data Files" folder name is causing the issue. I can't tell for sure because the Last Run Result is 0xFFFFFFFF.

Ideally I'd like to save incremental versions by using the file date trick, but at this point I'd be happy to just get one scheduled task working.

Comment: The whole `/tr` command should be in double quotes, so schtasks.exe can parse it as a single argument. Internally the file path `D:\Quickbooks Data Files` should be in single quotes, which schtasks.exe will replace with double quotes in the stored command line. For example: `schtasks /create /sc hourly /tn "Backup QB every hour" /tr "wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:R:\QBBackups\ -include:'D:\Quickbooks Data Files'"`.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the feedback. I included the double and single quotes just as you suggested but it's still coming back with the Last Run Result of 0xFFFFFFFE 

I wrote exactly what you gave as an example but it didn't work, so I changed it to the internal drive for the backupTarget in case that was causing problems (example: `schtasks /create /sc hourly /tn "Backup QB every hour" /tr "wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:D:\QBBackups\ -include:'D:\Quickbooks Data Files'"`) but that didn't work either.

Comment: Before the exit code was -1 (0xFFFFFFFF), and now it's changed to -2 (0xFFFFFFFE)? I think this means the user account you're using isn't a member of either the administrators or backup operators groups -- probably because the access token is UAC restricted and you need to elevate. Change the command to use the "highest" runlevel, e.g. `schtasks /create /sc hourly /tn "Backup QB every hour" /rl highest /tr "wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:R:\QBBackups\ -include:'D:\Quickbooks Data Files'"`.

Comment: @eryksun I thought the same as well, so I went ahead and ran it with `/rl highest` but it's still coming back with `0xFFFFFFFE`.

I'm running as admin on this server FWIW.

Comment: Maybe it's prompting for confirmation and failing. Try adding the `-quiet` command line argument to the wbadmin command. Also, is the target a mapped drive? If so, try using the full UNC path instead.

Comment: Also, just to make sure everything is ok with access, create another task that runs `cmd /k whoami /groups /fo list` with the highest run level. Confirm that `BUILTIN\Administrators` is present and enabled.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for sticking with me. 
I'm not entirely sure how to create a task that runs `cmd` but I ran `whoami /groups /fo list` and it came back with the following:

`Group Name: BUILTIN\Administrators
Type: Alias
SID: S-1-5-32-544
Attributes: Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner`

Unfortunately, adding `-quiet` didn't change anything.

Comment: Adding a task that runs cmd.exe should work the same, e.g. `schtasks /create /sc hourly /tn ShowAccountGroups /rl highest /tr "cmd /k whoami /groups /fo list"`. You can run it manually via `schtasks /run /tn ShowAccountGroups`. It should run on your current desktop. You can disable it afterward via `schtasks /change /disable /tn ShowAccountGroups`.

Comment: Thanks. It came back with the same as I posted above: 
`Group Name: BUILTIN\Administrators Type: Alias SID: S-1-5-32-544 Attributes: Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner`

It's enabled and present.